# Highlight currently selected option for dropdown form options in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I highlight the option based on the page the user is currently on?

E.g. If on Beds page, Beds option is selected.

This is inside of a wordpress sidebar text widget so it is not coded separately on each page. I guess maybe javascript would be needed to detect what page it's on?

```
<form>
<select onChange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="#">Select a Category</option>
<option value="https://www.furnishare.it/shop/">Shop All</option>
<option value="/product-category/beds/">Beds</option>
<option value="/product-category/chairs/">Chairs</option>
<option value="/product-category/decor/">Decor</option>
<option value="/product-category/dressers/">Dressers</option>
<option value="/product-category/sofas/">Sofas</option>
<option value="/product-category/storage/">Storage</option>
<option value="/product-category/tables/">Tables</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd create two classes, 'active' and 'inactive' and assign the active class to the page that is currently displayed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify! This is inside of a wordpress sidebar text widget so it is not coded separately on each page. I guess maybe javascript would be needed to detect what page it's on?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to get the url pathname:

```
window.location.pathname
```

I would suggest that you do this in a JS file rather than inline HTML. The implementation (jsfiddle wasn't saving for some reason):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvEeMY

Make sure to un-comment the commented location line to get it working on your webpage:

```
var location = window.location.pathname;
```

Note that I would highly recommend not dealing with DOM events using attributes like onClick ... but to answer your question I've written the pure JS code above.

Edit: Using location.pathname requires you to use full paths starting after your domain but since your implementation was already doing so in select > option values I've taken the liberty to simplify it with location.pathname.